# Big char array, how to optimize work with it?

Tags: java, optimization

I need to optimize work of array of chars with possible number 100000.
Task to rewrite original(or write new each time) array with some algorithm, each time make it smaller, thus I will have 1 char at the end.
100000->99999->...1
It seems that work with char array that way is time-consuming.

How is it possible to optimize this task?

Comment: I would first implement it naïvely and see if that is actually a problem. I would think at least when you're only modifying the original array - i.e. not making many copies - it shouldn't be so slow because the memory would only be allocated once

Comment: To help you optimize the code, we'd need to know what you're trying to do, to see if a better algorithm might be the answer, or we'd need to see the actual code, to see if it can be improved. Question is too broad.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. The problem was in algorithm. I made it 3 times faster than it was but it still not enough for arrays >50000. But I will try to do it myself.